# UWP - OneDrive file download error: “Access to the path '…' is denied” when using sample code from MS Graph team

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I'm working on this exercise from Microsoft Graph team: [Access and download files from OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/3-exercise-access-files-onedrive). And I'm getting the following Access denied error on the following code at the end under the section: `Download a file from the user's OneDrive`:

> > Access to the path 'C:\DotNETCore2019\UWP\AccessFilesTrainingCourse\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\driveItem_17B6A4972C38846A!2923.file' is denied.

**Remarks with Question**: Error occurs at line `var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);` of the code below. I know that UWP apps can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). According to this official link, one of those default locations is `Application install directory` which during debug mode is supposed to be `...\bin\debug` folder. And the above linked tutorial from MS Graph team does not mention declaring a capability in the app's Package.appxmanifest file. So, why the error and how can we resolve it `without` declaring `broadFileSystemAccess` capability - as you don't want go free for all scenario?

**Code**:

```
// request 3 - download specific file
var fileId = "REPLACE_THIS"; //I have correctly placed corresponding fileid here
var request = client.Me.Drive.Items[fileId].Content.Request();

var stream = request.GetAsync().Result;
var driveItemPath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "driveItem_" + fileId + ".file");
var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.CopyTo(driveItemFile);
Console.WriteLine("Saved file to: " + driveItemPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path instead of System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). The default location is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\your package name\LocalState

Comment: So, Microsoft Graph team is doing it wrong in the tutorial in the link I provided above, correct?

Comment: The tutorial is a .NET Core console app while you are writing a UWP